# Calling a function which belongs to another class

Tags: c++

I'm just wondering if there is a way to call a function from another class which is not a derived class.

For example...

If I have class Square which has a function colour, if I have another class Triangle, totally unrealated to Square, can I somehow call the colour funciton of Square on a Triangle object?

I'm wondering if friend can be used here, but from what I have read, it can't, unless I've misunderstood what I've read.

What is the best way to implement this without creating an inheritance relationship?

Comment: What's your color function doing in Square if it makes sense to apply it to a Triangle? More generally, when you find yourself wanting to do this, your function is in the wrong class (or shouldn't be in a class at all).

Answer (score 1):

If what your seeking to do is something like this:

```
Square s;
Triangle t;
t.colour(); // invoke Square::colour() on a Triangle
```

I'm sorry but you can't, unless you declare a function in Triangle which simply mimics what `Square::colour` does.

A wise option if you really need that function to be shared is to declare it as a standalone templated function like this:

```
template<typename Shape>
void colour(Shape s){
  //Do stuff
}
```

then in order to allow this access to the inner guts of Triangle and Square, make `void colour<Triangle>()` and `void colour<Square>()` friends of the appropriate classes.

Comment: yay for templates and static polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, your request is not possible.  The colour method is encapsulated within square and will not apply to an unrelated object of a difference class.  Either inherit (from shape - I know you said no inheritance), or re-implement the colour method for square as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry to bum you out. But i would recommend using a base class 'shape', and derive shapes from this class.

```
class Abc //Abstract base class
{
    public:
        virtual ~Abc();                             //destructor
        virtual double Color();           
        virtual double Area() const = 0;                  //pure virtual, MUST be overridden
    private:
        //specific variables that apply to all shapes
};

class Square : public Abc //derived class from pure virtual class
{
    public:
        Square();
        virtual double Color();
        virtual double Area() const; //redefine color here
        ~Square(){}
    private:
        //square vars here
};
```